# Музыка из ВК на сайт

Tags: html, веб-программирование, вконтакте, аудио

Есть ли способ сделать так, чтобы у меня на сайте плеер подтягивал треки из ВК?
Сперва думал, что всё элементарно: через инспектор нашёл путь к файлу, вставил его в плеер на сайте. Всё круто, всё работает! Но потом люди стали жаловаться, что треки не играют...
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Понаблюдав за этим, я понял, что ВК через время меняет названия файлов. И даже когда у меня всё играет, человек с другого IP не может прослушать...
Может кто-то посоветует что-то?

Comment: Дык он подтягивает аудио из аудиосписка пользователей. То, что вы видите `u253861761` это значит что запись взята у юзера, с `id` 253861761. Думаю, ссылка на конкретную запись будет активна, пока юзер её не удалит. А тогда придется искать аналогичную запись у другого пользователя. А пока её пользователь у себя не удалит - ссылка не меняется и всегда одинаковая

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, там кажется в ссылку еще и ключ доступа вставлен и он генерируется с привязкой то ли к ip, то ли к сессии, так что по прямым ссылкам ни аудио, ни видео с вк не стянуть (для другого пользователя).

Comment: @Visman Да вроде бы нет. Это всякие ключи надо при работе с `API`, а напрямую всё вроде бы работает. Например, вот возьмите и вставьте в браузер `https://psv4.vk.me/c521513/u352105/audios/8c0c44f2d2cd.mp3`  все работает. Да и даже ТС сказал, что у него в начале все работало)) Думаю, в данном случае просто должно быть место где аудиозаписи будут храниться и никогда не удаляться.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, 404 ошибка ;)

Comment: @Visman Ничего не знаю. И chrome и ff открывают на воиспроизведение, и даже бедненький IE предлагает открыть или сохранить. Не умеете копипастить)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, значит ссылка завязана на ip, если вы там не заходите на всех браузерах под одним акком вк. Если у вас динамический ip, то перегрузите модем и посмотрите результат.

Comment: @Visman Да, вы правы.

Comment: У меня тоже 404

Comment: Тоже пытался так сделать. Увы, ссылки на аудио там динамические и привязаны то ли к ip, то ли к сессти. Это было сделано намеренно, дабы человеки не использовали ВК, как хост для аудиозаписей без ведома самого сайта. Я полагаю, эта возможность доступна исключительно через api (а она доступна)

Answer (score 3):

*Вкратце так:*
При загрузке страницы vk.com с вашими аудиозаписями, для каждой песни генерируется новый URL, по которому она доступна только с IP адреса, с которого загружена страница. При попытке зайти на этот URL с другого IP, выдается ошибка 404.

Что же касается Вашего сайта, то для проигрывания музыки вк, я бы запрашивал список нужных аудиозаписей из VK API (см. больше http://vk.com/dev).

Однако, то, что Вы хотите сделать не задумано строгой администрацией ВК и будет жестоко предотвращаться. Чтобы получить список каких-любо аудио из ВК, необходима авторизация в VK API, а значит и соответствующая кнопка на сайте. Авторизация является годной пока не поступил запрос в API из страны, отличающейся от той, где была произведена авторизация. При этом ВК требует капчу.

Если я правильно понял, что Вы хотите сделать, то это невозможно. Доступ к аудиозаписям ВК без авторизации закрыт.

Я решил эту проблему, заведя отдельный сервис для скачивания музыки с вк, где пользователи логинились, а результат их логина (`access token` - см. VK API) я сохранял в базу и позже использовал в основном проекте.

Вся информация взята из моего годового опыта по обману API ВКонтакте. (**Годно на весну 2015, может меняться в будущем**).

Желаю удачи в этом непростом деле.